# CI-Neo4jPHP, getting labels from a node

Tags: codeigniter, neo4j, neo4jphp

This script below writen in CI and Neo4jPHP environment.

```
    $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client("localhost", 7474);
    $client->getTransport()->setAuth("admin","password");

    $all_labels = $client->getLabels();
    foreach ($all_labels as $key=>$a_label)
    {
        echo $key.": ".$a_label->getName()."\n";
    }
```

List of labels expected,
but i didn't get anything.

Comment: What returns `var_dump($all_labels);` ? And how did you build the client ?

Comment: I have edited the script  to show how $client was built.
Actually the problem is "how to parse the array of label object".

Comment: Solved!. Just check the libraries/Everyman/Neo4j/Label.php and have found a ::getName(). But still need your opinion. It was a good practice or not. Thank you and sorry for a little bit naive.
I have edited the script again.

Comment: If you want good practices, you should use a client that is frequently updated. Otherwise I don't see any bad practices to use static methods.

Comment: Thank You Chris. You are right. I have to underline your advice.